# How Can I Filter End Date Using Angluarjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I want to filtering the items like (Start and End Date)  which is based on `Due_date` using the daterange functionality in meanjs app...... [My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxqVJmpl3T88eZV5oWrX?p=preview)

- Please look at my plunker to reference.
- I Have displaying `Due_date`, so this is the field I want to use for filtering.
- I have used some functionality to add `invoice_Date` and `terms`, which provides the answer like `Due_date`. **for exmple:-** invoice_date : `2016-09-10`, terms : `6`, the answer I got Due_date : `16-09-2016`
- so what I excatly looking for , I want to filter the `Due_date` as start date and end date : **for example:-** if we select start date like `16-09-2016` and end date is `25-09-2016` in table these two transaction only need to display or filter... so I have used daterange filter to achieve this solution,
- I can able to filter `start date` perfectly , but unable to filter the `End date` , if we select `End date` it's not showing proper transaction in table..**Example**:- `startdate` :- `16-09-2016` then if we select `end date` like 28-09-2016 ,it should need to display three transaction, but only two transaction is displaying in table.... [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxqVJmpl3T88eZV5oWrX?p=preview)

**Controller:**

```
 .filter("myfilter", function() {
   return function(items, from, to) {
     var df = from;
       var dt =to;
         var result = [];   

      for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var date = new Date(items[i].invoice_date);
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(items[i].terms));
           var tf = date;
             if (tf > df && tf < dt)  {
               result.push(items[i]);
            }
        }   
         console.log(items);
        return result;
  };
});
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
```

**Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="data in  record | myfilter:from:to"
```

This below the filed need to filter in table:-

**Due_date:-**

```
<td> {{addDays(data.invoice_date,data.terms) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
```

- I have created plunker for referrence:- [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxqVJmpl3T88eZV5oWrX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) for datetime operations,

```
var date = moment(items[i].invoice_date).add(items[i].terms,'d');
if(date.isAfter(from) && date.isBefore(to)){
  .....
}
```

Comment: @ jerry chen Thanks for your valuable answer , can you please update plunker as well to know the solution...bcoz we tried out your answer in plunker it's not working, so please update plunker......thanks

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam http://plnkr.co/edit/pwlZnMFG03TzOjrDzSfB?p=preview check the end month, it is Oct not Sep.